# getting an index of a character

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem getting an index of the character '-' of a string. Let me explain my problem.
First I have to read a line from a text file. The only line in the text file is           "Beta  =  62.5  *  (Sigma – Delta)  /  125"

```
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(openPath, Encoding.Default); 

while (rdr.Peek() != -1)
{
     string strInput = rdr.ReadLine();
}
```

then I need to get the index of char '-'.

```
int col = strInput.IndexOf('-');
```

After the above line 'col' is equal to -1. But as you can see the '-' character is in the above mentioned string which read from the text file. 
I couldn't figure out why I'm getting -1 as the index of '-'. help me...

Comment: It looks like in your file you have a dash not a '-' char. These are 2 different character. Could you confirm?

Comment: Copy the – from your text file, paste it into your code, then try again. Also, put a breakpoint on the `IndexOf` line and check the value of `strInput`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two characters are not the same. Look at the length of them:

```
–
```

(this is called an en-dash, equal to the width of the ASCII character N)

vs

```
-
```

(this is a normal ascii hyphen, or minus sign)

Amend your indexof to use the en-dash (–) instead of the hyphen (-) and you should get proper results.

Edit: Thanks to sixlettervariables for correct terminology

Comment: The first one is known as an *em* dash while the second one is an *en* dash. They are so-named as their widths equate to a capital M and N respectively (though often the en dash is half the width of the em dash). If you solve crossword puzzles, you're no stranger to ems and ens.

Comment: Actually, an em-dash looks like —, while his string contained – (en-dash?), and he was searching for -. This gets confusing.

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom: Hello font-magic, you're correct so I'll restate: The first one is an *en* dash and the second one is a hyphen. Lord help us if he gets digit dashes in there...

Answer (score 1):

You are not searching for the same character, the character you are searching for should be `'–'` and not `'-'`

Try his line:

```
int col = a.IndexOf('–');
```

Comment: I was half way typing the exact same answer :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Add (temporarily) a line to your code, just before `int col = strInput.IndexOf('-');`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(String.Equals(strInput, "Beta = 62.5 * (Sigma – Delta) / 125");
```